# What is the relation between Akasha(आकाश) and Kālá(काल) in Advaita Vedanta?

Tags: advaita

What is the exact nature of their relationship? Does one arise from the other? I have an operational hypothesis that Kālá is an emanation of Akasha - unfortunately, my hunt to gain clarity on the exact mechanisms is still very much a work in progress (in that it is inarticulate).

Comment: "It looks scientific speculation (space and time - according to theory of relativity)!" - @Pandya - Please explain your comment.

Comment: Akasha is space and what your hypothesis is saying, is that space generates time. Bramha created this universe and the first element to manifest itself was aakasha and other 4 followed but the notion of time applies to bramha (kalpa, mahakalpa) etc.

Comment: @Yogi Do (and if so how) physical space and physical time correspond to Akasha and Kala respectively in the Advaitic thought? My understanding (from reading Vashishta's Yoga so far) is that Akasha is the "first" emanation brought about by pure consciousness beholding itself, there is no mention or supposition of time or brahma explicitly in this process.

Comment: Vashishtas yoga you mean yoga vashishta? Many scholars consider it to be later interpolation. Bramhanada purana can help you here.

Comment: @Yogi Thanks for your pointer, checking it out. Apart from Brahmanda Purana, are there any other texts that establish the relation between Akasha and Kala with equal if not more adhikara in the context of Advaita? Additionally, if you so please, can you refer me to traditional references that establish Yoga Vashishta is a later interpolation? Would be interested in the context of its origins.

Comment: All the other texts which i know are nigamas which have restrictions on reading etc.

Comment: @anuvaramban Adi Shankara says that the apparent creation proceeds through appearance of space-time. See my question (and answer) [here.](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17066/where-do-vedas-state-universe-being-a-projection-in-space-time)

Comment: @anuvaramban You can see Wikipedia for [Yoga Vasistha.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Vasistha#cite_note-5) It says "somewhere between 6th-century to as late as 14th-century CE,".. but Wikipedia is not a reliable source.. Regarding traditional sources it was referred by Vaishnava Acharya Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, and also commented by Madhavacharya (brother of Sayana)... Svetasvatara Upanishad Bhasya of Adi Shankara also qyotes Yoga Vasistha... but Svetasvatara Bhasya of Shankara is of doubtful authenticity...

Comment: @anuvaramban Wikipedia also says "Atreya in 1935 suggested that the text must have preceded Gaudapada and Adi Shankara, because it does not use their terminology, but does mention many Buddhist terms.[9] Dasgupta, a contemporary of Atreya, states that the text includes verses of earlier text, such as its III.16.50 is identical to one found in Kalidasa's Kumarasambhava, thus the text must be placed after the 5th-century.[9]"

Comment: @Yogi Thanks, could you state the name of these nigama texts or the Guru Paramparas where these are followed? Thanks!

Comment: @Tezz Thanks for Q&A link. As you rightly observed, wikipedia cannot be considered a reliable source (I have seen the wiki page before but do not rely on it - need to do my own verification!)

Comment: Not a saastric one but here is a thought - and I don't think one gave birth to the other ; time existed prior, if - the relationship between the two is that their union results in matter.

Comment: @moonstar2001 If time existed prior and one didn't give birth to the other, then how to explain origin of space?

Comment: How can we prove that space gave birth to time

Comment: Perhaps we should take this to chat?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yes, we can discuss it here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy