# Where do Vedas state Universe being a projection in space-time?

Tags: scripture, vedas, history, time, creation

Vedas state about Cyclic nature of time as discussed in [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14913/where-does-rig-veda-states-about-cyclical-nature-of-creation/14914#14914) But are there **any statement in Vedas which state about Universe being projected as space-time ?**

<sub>As a sidenote, Adi Shankaracharya in his famous [Dakshinamurty stotram:](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_shiva-dakshinamurthy_stotram.php) states how apparent creation proceeds with the appearance of space-time through Maya:</sub>

> बीजस्याऽन्तरिवाङ्कुरो जगदिदं प्राङ्गनिर्विकल्पं पुनः
>   मायाकल्पितदेशकालकलना वैचित्र्यचित्रीकृतम् ।
>  
>   **This World** is Like a Sprout of a Seed Within which transforms what is Changeless state Before, **appear Again as Space and Time,** and endless Varieties of Pictures over it; all due to the Creation of Maya,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

19.53 is a Hymn to Kala in Atharvaveda also known as [**Kala Sukta**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19053.htm). In it's third verse it states:

> पूर्ण कुम्भोदिः काल आहितस्तं वै पश्यामो बहुदा नु सन्तः । [AtharvaVeda 19.53.3]
>  
>   **A full pot has been placed in Time and it is that which we see manifoldly.**

Here a full pot ie. Purna Kumbha represents Hiranyagarbha (Sum total of the Universe) ie. It also represents space of Universe.

And when it is placed on Time then it causes people to see the manifold creation.

Translating the verse partly:

> पूर्ण कुम्भोदिः काल आहितस्तं
>   pūrṇa kumbhodiḥ kāla āhitastaṃ
>   
>   **A full pot has been placed in Time.**

Round pot is called Kumbha and it is called full. Hiranyagarbha is round ie. also called golden egg and it is full as it represents sum total of Universe. And the second part states:

> वै पश्यामो बहुदा नु सन्तः
>   vai paśyāmo bahudā nu santaḥ
>   
>   **That is what is seen as Many.**

It uses the word "Vai Pashyãmo" ie. "That is seen." ie. It is suggesting about apparent nature of creation just as projection / just appearing only.

The translation of Griffith is not so good but still it makes sense. Griffth [translates](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19053.htm) it as:

> On Time is laid an overflowing beaker: **this we behold** in many a place **appearing.**